Ошибка C2207 при обращении к ссылке на объект, который находится в векторе
Проще показать код чем объяснить в чем проблема. Всю голову сломал!
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Human;
class Team {
public:
    vector<Human*> people;
    void print_team() {
    cout <<"Работник "<< people[0]->name;//Ошибка 2027 использование неопределенного типа "Human"
}
};

class Human {
public:
Human(string _n) {
    name = _n;
}
    void add_to_team(Team* t) {
    t->people.push_back(this);
}
//private:
string name;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    Team janitors;
    Human vasya("Вася");
    vasya.add_to_team(&janitors);
    janitors.print_team();
}

Когда выполняю трассировку, данные в векторе есть. Но при попытке вывести их выдает 2027. Что я делаю не так?

Пытаетесь использовать сущности до объявления...
Откуда в вашем коде компилятору в этот момент знать, что у Human есть член name и что он собой представляет?
Делайте так:
class Team {
public:
    vector<Human*> people;
    void print_team();
};

class Human {

.....

};

void Team::print_team()
{
    cout <<"Работник "<< people[0]->name;
}


Я так и подумал. Вы подтвердили мои мысли. Спасибо за ответ.

Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...
